# How safe are the ferries in Indonesia?

Tags: public-transport, safety, transportation, ferries, indonesia

I'm planning a holiday to Indonesia and want to visit multiple islands. I had thought to take ferries between the different islands. However, a lot of people have told me bad things about the ferries in Indonesia, including:

(a) The ferries have far too many people packed onto them, well above the limit imposed for health & safety reasons

(b) The ferries are not seaworthy and therefore likely to be involved in a tragic accident

(c) The ferries will give you a rough crossing to the point of making you ill

Basically, I just want to know if the situation is really this bad. For example, are there safety records of Indonesian ferries to give an objective view of the situation?

To be more objective, some pointer questions are:

1. Are these things really true, or just people complaining without good reason?
2. What kind of things can go wrong if the ferry operators put more people on than the limit?
3. How frequently do accidents really happen on ferry routes compared to how many ferry crossings there are in a year? For example, is it significantly more likely to be killed in an Indonesian shipping accident than in a plane accident?
4. What are the other ways of travelling between Indonesian islands and the benefits/disadvantages of each? Flying is an obvious one, but is this really practical (in order to reach typical tourist destinations quickly enough to fit into, say, a 10-day long holiday) and does it have any similar safety risks associated with local carriers?

Comment: Too many questions. Please have a read of the [help] and consider splitting your questions into separate ones.

Comment: Also asking for recommendations is generally frowned upon, as seen in the [help].

Comment: I've heard scary stories about airplanes in Indonesia, too.  The truth is that in a country with less (enforced) regulations / lower standards on public transportation safety, you might have a higher risk of getting into an accident.

Comment: Apologies if I did something wrong, I am quite new here. I did read the help center before writing this question, and I thought it said my questions should not be subjective, so I tried to ask specific questions to guide a full answer, as I couldn't fit all the detail into the short description of my question. If you would rather I raised four separate questions, I can do that, but they are all related and asking the same kind of thing, so I thought it would seem overkill to have four separate entries on travel.SE, as there would be a lot of overlap.

Comment: I would say q1 & 3 are basically asking the same thing, so could be one question.  q2 - I'm not sure what you're expecting apart from "boat sinks or people get injured, or nothing".  Q4 would be a standalone and to make it not subjective, don't ask for recommendations. Instead just ask for the various means of transportation between islands. If you're still concerned about the safety, perhaps ask for a comparison of the various means of transporation?  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: As for asking for recommendations, I did see that as an "avoid this" type thing in the help center, but I didn't understand it, because whenever someone asks a "how can I do this" style question they are asking for recommendations. The truth is, I don't necessarily know all the possible transport options and so I am asking for the community to tell me the options together with their benefits/downsides. Does the fact that I used the word "recommend" instantly make my question off-topic?

Comment: Q1 is about all three of the "bad things I have heard" whereas Q3 is drilling down specifically into the second of the three. As for Q2, yes I still need to know the answer, because I can't understand how having too many people on a boat could make it more likely that people could get injured. Q4 could be a separate question but then it makes this one rather negative - people could be saying that they don't agree with Indonesian ferries, but are not allowed to propose an alternative within the scope of my question.

Comment: I understand now about recommendations after reading a comment by a user on another question saying "Keep in mind that what is the 'best' way is a bit subjective since what's best for one person is not what's best for everybody". So I've edited my question to remove the word "recommend" and phrase in a better way which is less subjective. By the way, I notice my question was edited to replace the specific question bullets with numbers. I deliberately didn't do that when first asking, because I wanted it to be clear that these are not separate questions. But okay, I'll leave it the way it is.

Comment: @Kidburla, they certainly appear to be separate questions, as I said above.  I numbered them for convenience as my comment above talked about Q1, Q2 etc and I just wanted it to be clear what I was addressing. You've addressed the subjective part, but multiple distinct questions is still likely to be closed :/

Comment: Okay, I've re-worded the question again. But this is the best way I can think of.

Comment: I have edited the question in an attempt to focus it (by removing the request for alternatives) and more objective (by asking for safety records). If you feel I have vandalized your question, please feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable to ask about the safety record of the ferries in a given country. The Philippines has a very scary record and South Korea has a scarily inconsistent record, for instance. If it's answerable for those countries it's answerable for arbitrary countries.

Comment: @Flimzy thank you for your good faith edit. However I fear the question becomes too broad when you remove the pointer questions - unfortunately this also removes the sense from the multiply-upvoted answer! However I have kept your title edit and your rewording of my summary, and your mention of safety records.

Comment: @Kidburla: You have made the question far more broad again. I would vote to close it again but (un?)fortunately, I'm only allowed to VtC once.

Comment: @Flimzy how is "I just want to know if the situation is really this bad" actually *less* broad than giving specific pointer questions?

Comment: @Flimzy according to my history view you weren't part of the original VtC? Anyway, you said before "If you feel I have vandalized your question, please feel free to roll back my edit", well I rolled back 50% of your edit and kept the rest of your changes, so I feel I have more than acted in accordance with your wishes.

Comment: @Kidburla: I VtCed, then I retracted my vote after my edit.

Comment: @Kidburla: Your question #4 is the part that makes it the most broad. Asking for alternative methods of transport has nothing to do with asking about the safety of ferries, and would/should stand as its own question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One by one:

1. **Yes**, Indonesian ferries are that bad.  Overcrowding is rife, safety precautions are often non-existent, and the open sea can often be rough.  As a simple example, Jakarta Globe's category "Indonesia boat accident" has [at least 7 separate sinkings that killed people](http://thejakartaglobe.beritasatu.com/tag/indonesia-boat-accident/) for 2014 alone, and see the links [in this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29000/how-to-get-from-flores-to-lombok-by-sea-with-stops) for some stories of a typical tourist ferry crossing (Flores-Lombok).
2. Either a) nothing happens, or b) the ferry sinks and you most likely die.
3. Indonesian planes are a *lot* safer: [nobody has died in a commercial airline crash since 2011](http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Country=PK), and that was a turboprop on a marginal airline (Nusantara).  Excluding the Sukhoi Superjet crash (which was a demo flight of a new Russian plane at an airshow, not a commercial flight), the last crash of a jet plane was in 2007.
4. Indonesia is all islands, so your options are to take a boat or fly.  But flying is extremely practical (considerably more practical than ferries, IMHO): fares are very cheap and the larger carriers (Garuda, Lion, Air Asia) are quite reliable and safe.

It's worth noting, though, that there are large differences between the ferry operators as well.  National operator [Pelni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelni) hasn't had a boat sink since 1981, despite plying all year around all around the backwaters of Indonesia.  The large car ferries (Sumatra-Java, Java-Bali, Bali-Lombok) are also pretty solid.  It's the small speedboats plying off the beaten track in bad weather that are most likely to kill you.

Last but not least, if you've only got 10 days, just how many islands were you planning to visit?  You could *easily* spend all that time on say Bali alone, and 10 days to get through even Java and Bali would be pretty rushed in my book.

Comment: +1, The only thing to add regarding Air travel in Indonesia is that while it's not as risky as ferries, it's also not very reliable. So make sure you do not rely on certain departure/arrival times.

Comment: @uncovery Depends on the airline though.  I've never had a problem with Garuda, while ♫ it's Merpati and I'll fly if I want to ♫ is infamous for delays and cancellations.

Comment: If you're travelling with the aim of seeing rude ignorant Australians getting drunk and vomiting and offending the locals, you might not need to go anywhere besides Bali d-;

Comment: @jpatokal Same as with the ferries, also among the airlines there are more and less reliable ones. Garuda is surely the best in Indonesia.

Comment: "hasn't had a boat sink since 1981!"  gosh!  :-)

Comment: I've just run across your answer. As there may be more boats than planes in Indonesia in particular, I'm wondering if the *per person, per ride* risks are actually greater for ferry trips than for plane trips. I haven't figured out how to look his up anywhere though, or how it compares to fatalities by bus or passenger cars.

Comment: The *nobody has died in an airline crash since 2011* is out of date since [Lion Air Flight 610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_Air_Flight_610).